# C++ | Помогите доделать функцию что возвращает число вхождений подстроки

Tags: c++, циклы

Предполагается что функция вернёт 2, а возвращает 3. Можно исправить?

```
int CountChar(string text, string text_char) {
int res = 0, check = 0;
int text_size = StrSize(text);
int char_size = StrSize(text_char);
for (int i = 0; i < text_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < char_size; j++) {
        if (text[i] == text_char[j]) {
            if (text[i + j] == text_char[j + j]) {
                res++;
            }
        }
    }
}
return res;
}
   int main() {
   cout << CountChar("Hello_|_Poppy_|_", "_|_") << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: У `std::string` есть метод `find` почему не используете?

Comment: Как вариант `std::for_each()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант:

```
int CountChar(string text, string text_char) {
  int res = 0, check = 0;

  int text_size = text.length();
  int char_size = text_char.length();

  for (int i = 0; i < text_size; ) {
    check=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < char_size; j++) {
        // Проверяем на совпадение 
        // и учитываем размер строки string text
        if ( i+j < text_size && text[i+j] == text_char[j])
            check++; // Совпал один символ
        else
            break;
    }
    if ( check == char_size ) { // Сколько символов совпало?
        i += check; // Перемещаемся за совпадение
        res++;
    }
    else
        i++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Только сейчас заметил свою ошибку. Использовал в вопросе функцию которой здесь не написал, рад что вы поняли. Первый ответ почему-то выдаёт ошибку. Второй работает хорошо. Благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Мое предложение:

```
int CountChar(string text, string text_char) {
int res = 0, check = 0;
int text_size = StrSize(text);
int char_size = StrSize(text_char);
for (int i = 0; i < text_size; i++) {
    if (text[i]==text_char[0]){
        for (int j=0; j < char_size; j++){
            if (text[i+j]==text_char[j]) {check++;}
        };
    if (check == char_size) {res++};
    check = j;
    };
};
return res;
};

   int main() {
   cout << CountChar("Hello_|_Poppy_|_", "_|_") << endl;
   return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Как написано в документации к [`std::string`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) есть метод [`std::string::find()`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) если его использовать код станет сильно короче:

```
int CountChar( std::string text, std::string text_char ) {
    int res = 0;
    for( size_t p = 0; ( p = text.find( text_char, p ) ) != std::string::npos; ++res )
       p += text_char.length();
    return res;
}
```

[Живой пример](https://ideone.com/VXU8KH)

Comment: Судя по вопросу надо на циклах: c++ циклы. Может в учебных целях

Comment: @Виктор Ответы на SO предназначены не только для автора вопроса.